# Column name in two lines DOJO

Tags: css, dojo

I have a DOJO table. How can I write the column name in two lines?

```
      {classes: "title", name: "I/P Voltage (V)", field: "mainsVoltage",styles: 'text-align: center;', width: "100px" }
```

I want the I/P Voltage in one line and (V) in next line and in the center. How can I do that?

Comment: Setting some fixed width will do that.. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZPG3/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML within the name in `dojox/grid/DataGrid`.  So you'd want:

`{classes: "title", name: "I/P Voltage<br>(V)", field: "mainsVoltage",styles: 'text-align: center;', width: "100px" }`